# Blender Game Engine: While mouse button is pressed

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a first person shooter game and I want to make it so when the right mouse button is being held down the, the player looks down the sights, and when the right button is released it returns to the normal view.
So this is the normal view from the camera:
[image: normal view]

And this is what I want it to look like when the player is holding the right mouse button (The gun moved to the left an backwards a bit:)
[image: zoomed view]

Another problem I encountered while trying to do this was that I already have a shoot animation, so how do I have different actions on one object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is actually rather easy to do this.

First, you need a cool gun, You already have on of those, so then next step is to make it my favorite color blue - 1BC8F7.

You can skip that step if you want, but the gun looks so much nicer blue :-)

I assume you are giving the gun recoil with logic like this.

[image]

To make your gun be able to aim from the sights, parent the gun to an empty.

[image]

The empty should be parented to the camera.

[image]

Now, if we move the camera, everything should move with it.

[image]

This is good. Now, your recoil animation can play on the gun, but it will not move into place yet.

[image]

We can fix this by animating the empty to move into place when the mouse is clicked, and then move back out of place when the mouse is released.

[image]

Believe it or not, we can do this with one animation.  I am going to be using the right mouse button to aim the gun to the center, because it makes funner gameplay, however, it is just a simple to do it with the left mouse..

[image]

This is using the right mouse to aim the gun into place.

[image]

## It works- Yay!

Now for the left mouse.

You only need to change a few things to your existing logic on the empty, to get this setup.

[image]

I added a simply ground plane to see the gun's movement better.

[image]

Now we need to add a *Mouse Look* actuator

[image]

Now, we can test it.

[image]

I'm not happy with that quite yet, so I'm going to add a slow parent to the empty.

[image]

Now we can test it.

[image]

That looks much better! You could, of course, tweak the settings to make it exactly how you want your gun. I think bullets and muzzle flashes would seriously help - but they have nothing to do with this answer :-(

Comment: This works, thanks! But, maybe I've done something wrong, right click toggles aiming down the iron sight. Is there a way so that it's looking down the iron sight when I'm holding right mouse button then when I release the button it goes back to hip-fire? @X-27

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, try using the second method (the one using left click to aim down the sights) - then change the mouse sensor from left click to right click.

Comment: Another classic X-27 overkill answer :D +1

Comment: I sound like this guy! (no it's excitement not overkill)